# RxJava with multi network request

Tags: android, rx-java

Here is the code:

```
public class HomeDetails extends Model {

    public Home mHomeData;
    public AD mAdData;

    public HomeDetails(Api api, String url) {
        api.getHome(url, createHome(), this);
        api.getAd(url, createAD(), this);
    }

    private NetworkResponse.Listener<Home> createHome() {
        return new NetworkResponse.Listener<Home>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Home home) {
                mHomeData = home;
            }
        };
    }

    private NetworkResponse.Listener<AD> createAD() {
        return new NetworkResponse.Listener<AD>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(AD ad) {
                mAdData = ad;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I'd like to use RxJava to help me to know when the two requests are all done. if all is done, then execute another method.

Comment: do you want to run the requests in parallel?

Comment: yes, just combine them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Observable.create()` to create the two observable for the two network calls, then you can `concat()` or `zip()` them and execute whatever you want in the `onNext()`.

Comment: Fair enough ;-) Happy StackOverflow then.